# Why there is an error if I use same type parameter of a invoking object and argument object of same generic class?

Tags: java, generics

Here is the generic class

```java
class MyGen <T extends Number> {
    T ObjNum;

    MyGen( T obj){ ObjNum= obj; }
```

A method which is used to compare two type wrapper objects

```java
boolean AbsCompare( T Obj){
    if( Math.abs( ObjNum.doubleValue())== Math.abs( obj.doubleValue())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    } //class end here
```

Main class is

```java
class Sample{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyGen <Integer> Objint1= new MyGen( 99);
        MyGen <Integer> Objint2= new MyGen (100 );
    
        //Creating a integer type object 
        Integer Objint3=101;

        //using method to compare the objects 
        boolean b1= Objint1.AbsCompare( Objint2); //It shows an error
        boolean b2= Objint1. AbsCompare(Objint1); //It shows an error
        boolean b3= Objint1. AbsCompare( Objint3) ; // It does not shows an error
```

If the invoking object and the passing object as argument have same type then why it shows  error. And a same type Object is passed as argument which is not type of that generic  class is not shows any error

If I use in AbsCompare() method like this

```java
boolean AbsCompare( MyGen<T> obj)
```

Then both comparison between same generic class objects are fine, but simple Integer object comparison shows an error now and the method in if block

```
if(Math.abs(ObjNum.doubleValue())==Math.abs(Obj.doubleValue()))
```

The last `Obj.doubleValue()` shows an error.

I am in new to Java. Can anyone please help me the concept behind why these showing error are showing and how are they disappear when change the syntax.

Comment: You declare the method as `AbsCompare( T Obj)`, so in a generic object `MyGen <Integer> Objint1` you have `T` = `Integer`. So your method with resolved types would be `AbsCompare( Integer Obj)` and expects `Integer obj` as a parameter (Because T gets replaced by Integer).  I really don't understand why you are confused that you can't pass something other than the very parameter type you yourself declared into that method. This has little to do with generics. If you declare a method to take a certain type as a parameter then that is all the method will accept. `MyGen<Integer>` != `Integer`

Comment: Putting a `>` in front of text means that you are marking it as a citation. Don’t mark your own text as citation. Further, don’t use problem descriptions like “*shows an error*”. If you really have a reason to keep your error secret, explain why you can’t tell us the actual error. By the way, don’t write statements like `if(condition) return true; else return false;` Just write `return condition;`

Comment: I already tried explaining that to you. Because you declared your method to accept `T`, which is an `Integer` in your case. But you try to pass `MyGen<Integer>`. Your method expects `(Integer obj)` as a parameter and `MyGen<Integer> Objint1` is not `Integer`. It is `MyGen<Integer>`.

Comment: @OhGODSPIDERS , sorry Now I got the whole point . Kudos

Comment: This is the same reason why a method declared as `someMethod(Integer integer)` can not be called with `sometMethod(new ArrayList<Integer>())`. because just like a `List` that has `<Integer>` as a generic type is not a `Integer` itself, your own `MyGen` with the generic type of `<Integer>` is also not an `Integer` itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare your object both with instances of its own type (MyGen) and instances of T, then you have to create 2 separate methods:

```
boolean AbsCompare( T Obj){
    return if( Math.abs( ObjNum.doubleValue())== Math.abs( obj.doubleValue());
}
```

and

```
boolean AbsCompare(MyGen<T> myGen){
    return Math.abs(ObjNum.doubleValue())== Math.abs(myGen.ObjNum.doubleValue());
}
```

No wonder it's showing errors at the moment because you are trying to pass 2 entirely different types to the same method (MyGen and Integer). When you make an object generic as you did with MyGen, it has a has-a relationship with the object it wraps, while in the case of inheritance it has an is-a relationship with the object it inherits from. In order to pass objects to the same method you need inheritance, i.e. there should be an is-a relationship between them. Meaning if your object was:

```
MyGen extends Integer {
...
}
```

you would be able to pass both MyGen and Integer to AbsCompare method.